# Download .CSV/.TXT From asp.net page without prompt

Tags: asp.net, http, download, handler

I currently have a handler that when navigated to prompts the user to download a file.

I need to programmatically disable this box and allow for the file to auto download when that page is hit. Would it be easier to read that pages text and then rewrite my own file somehow?

Which would be the best approach and how would I go about doing it.

Currently I have

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context as HttpContext) Implements IHTTPHandler.ProcessRequest
Dim filename as String = myfile.csv
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
context.Response.WriteFile(filename)
End Sub
```

This currently prompts the user to choose a save location and file name etc etc before starting the download.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in a below response this has to be possible. Download sites automatically start downloads all the time as soon as you navigate there.

I have come across some other sites that mention IE settings could be changed? I don't know if this could be usful in finding a solution

[Super User disable Popup for download](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Your question is very unclear and probably impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You create a form on the page, hide it and have it downloaded via javascript. It might look something like below. You set up an html form, and have it submitted by Javascript when the page has loaded. I've just tested in Chrome / Firefox / IE. Think about it, those download sites you see that show a message like "Your download should begin within 5 seconds, if it does not click here...". You may want to include a direct link incase of any browser settings that may block.

Note use Response.Clear() prior to the other response code.

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<!-- Where /Download/GetFile will cause your code as posted to execute. -->

<form action="/Download/GetFile" id="form1" method="post"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("form1").submit();

</script>
```

Comment: So are you saying that in IE this will NOT give the user the prompt saying "Do you want to open or save this file?"  Because that is what I get when I test this code, and it sounds like that is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Good point, it cant be impossible if I have had it done to me before. I will try your solution when I get a chance and see if I get the same results. I added a link from a super user post that does it(could your settings need to be set up like this to ignore the prompt?)

Comment: Mike, you are right. I may have misinterpreted. Of course nothing you can code for can override browser settings such as prompting for save etc. I will leave post in case it is useful. Note that if you have control over which client is used, chrome didn't prompt for the download, as it is just text (not sure what would happen if .exe).

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  You don't have the right to forcibly download a file to another user's machine without their permission, so the browsers deliberately prevent it.  The whole reason that prompt is there is so that the user can be aware that the website is trying push something to their machine and allow them the option of allowing it.

Comment: True, but you can render in-browser by setting headers correctly (effectively removing the prompt, but still rendering the content without intervention). I'm not sure which case the OP wants though, so it'll be up to them to explain it further.

Comment: Your answer still prompts the user to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html). Internally it seems to use Applets or other mechanisms to save, but it might fit your needs.